# Can not get value by ajax query

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I using .net core. Have this class:

```
public class SentEmailItem
{
    public SentEmailItem()
    {
        Attachments = new List<AttachmentItem>();
    }


    public long PKID { get; set; }
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }
    public string EmailFrom { get; set; }
    public string Cc { get; set; }
    public string Bcc { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public List<string> EmailToList => EmailTo.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    public List<string> CcList => (Cc ?? string.Empty).Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    public List<string> BccList => (Bcc ?? string.Empty).Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    public List<AttachmentItem> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

And this method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendEmail(SentEmailItem item)
{
    EmailHelper.SendEmailAsync(item);

    return SuccessJsonResult();
}
```

But when called this method from ajax by this code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: self.sendEmailUrl,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ item: emaiItem })
}).done(function (json) {
    App.unblockUI();

    if (json.HasErrors) {
        var errorsHtml = $.map(json.Errors, function (x) { return "" + x.ErrorMessage + "<br/>"; }).join("");
        UIToastr.ShowMessage('error', 'Error', errorsHtml);
        return;
    }

    self.sendEmailCompleted(json);
});
```

I can't get data in my controller method. All data have null value. But in emaiItem placed in js value looks like:

```
Bcc : "Testmail@mail.com"
Body : "test body"
Cc : "Testmail@mail.com"
EmailFrom : "just3f@mail.com"
EmailTo : "Testmail@mail.com"
Subject : "Test subject"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `emaiItem` is already an object like this -

```
var emaiItem = {Bcc : "Testmail@mail.com",
Body : "test body",
Cc : "Testmail@mail.com",
EmailFrom : "just3f@mail.com",
EmailTo : "Testmail@mail.com",
Subject : "Test subject"};
```

If so, it could just use `JSON.stringify(emaiItem)`. Otherwise, you can hard-code the above `emaiItem`, and see those values populated at server-side.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(emaiItem)
}).done(function (json) {
    ...
});
```

### Solution

Replace with `JSON.stringify(emaiItem)`, and use `[FromBody]` attribute to force model binder to bind data from the request body.

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult SendEmail([FromBody]SentEmailItem item) 
{
}
```

Comment: Add this code: 
`console.log(JSON.stringify(emaiItem)); 
console.log(JSON.stringify({ item: emaiItem }));` and it looks like: 
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Au7PK_fpd9oYl0hRF4BYGq90Tj5w

Comment: `JSON.stringify(emaiItem)` fixes the original issue. Now, server throws  exception and returns 502 status code. Could you set a break point inside `public JsonResult SendEmail(SentEmailItem item)`, and step thought the code?

Comment: its just because i have `public List<string> EmailToList => EmailTo.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();` in class, but `EmailTo` is null.

Comment: Could you add `[FromBody]` to the parameter, and try again? `[HttpPost]public JsonResult SendEmail([FromBody]SentEmailItem item)`

Comment: The orignal problem is `JSON.stringify(emaiItem)`. Another problem is model binder confuses if we post complex object like `SentEmailItem`. We need to explicitly said how we want to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging your c# code to see if the back-end api is being hit? That would be a good place to start if not.

Comment: Yes. Method called, but all data is null
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Au7PK_fpd9oYl0opcLCrApQOQtpa